# Folder turned into file?

Tags: file-system

Normally "DCIM" is a folder in which all photos that were taken with camera are stored. When I tried to take a photo with Google Camera, the app instructed me to insert a sd card before taking photos (Nexus 5 doesn't support sd cards). I know that Google Camera also works without sd card, because it had been working before something messed up my Nexus's rom. I was looking with X-plore and ZArchiver and in both of them the folder "DCIM" appears as a file with a size of 0 bytes. I cannot delete this file, open it with an editor (Jota+) or create a folder with the same name and it is the only folder/file that is affected.

I'm using a Nexus 5 with Android 4.4.4 without any modification (like Cyanogen or root)

**Does someone know what could have happened to this folder and possibly how to restore the folder or delete the file without root or factory reset?** (If there's a way to delete this file, it wouldn't be a problem , because there wasn't a single photo inside before this happened.)

Comment: "something messed up my Nexus's rom" Would you care to be more specific about that?

Comment: Yep. Something (I don't know what) caused my Nexus's internal memory to show a folder as a file for which I hadn't any permissions. But this problem has gone, after a simple restart :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it. After doing a simple restart "DCIM" appeares as a normal folder. I still don't know what was causing this problem.

Comment: I have the same problem with 3 folders: Android, Telegram and Whatsapp. Unfortunately, the restart didn´t work. As in your case, it just happened. The files also show zero lenght but no disk space was freed, so I asume the files (plenty of them) are still there